how to create vector from 7 integers
I have seven integers of which I want to make a vector like this
std::cin >> a, b, c, d, e, f, g; // I have to do it like this
std::vector<int> v{a, b, c, d, e, f, g};

but it always returns the first number and then just zeros.
I don't really know what to do.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work-and-what-precedence-does-it-have

You should have a >> for each input variable, not a comma.

The commas don't do what you think they do.

PSA: Use loops instead of a ridiculous number of variables. push_back your numbers.

Create the vector first std::vector<int> values(7); then use a range based for loop to read the values for(auto& value : values) std::cin >> value;. There should not be 7 seperate input values to do what you want to do. Whoever is telling you "I have to do it like this" is wrong

Why do you have to do it like that? Who is forcing you?

I have to do it like this This way doesn't work.  Why do you have to do it like this?

It is for the qualifiying rounds of USACO, and they only provide this type of input (the bastards)

@SamVandenabeele they may be providing you input values in a particular format, but they shouldn't be dictating how your code needs to read in those values. That is up to you to decide.

The comma operator doesn't work the way you are thinking. It evaluates its left-hand and right-hand expressions and then returns only the result of its right-hand expression.  And operator>> has a higher precedence than the comma operator. So, the statement:
std::cin >> a, b, c, d, e, f, g;

Acts like you had written it like this:
(std::cin >> a), b, c, d, e, f, g;

Which is basically doing the same thing as this:
std::cin >> a;
b;
c;
d;
e;
f;
g;

That is why only a receives a value, and b..g are left untouched.
You need to instead use operator>> to read a value for each individual variable:
std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f >> g;

